# Brew unlinked kegs in your Cellar

Tags: git, macos, terminal, homebrew

When I run `brew doctor` on my terminal I get this output:

> Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar Leaving kegs unlinked
>   can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on those kegs to
>   fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
>
> ```
> automake
> libgpg-error
> libksba
> libtool
> ```

And then, when I try to link any package with `brew link packagename` command I get this kind of out put:

> Linking /usr/local/Cellar/automake/1.15...  Error: Could not symlink
>   share/info/automake-history.info /usr/local/share/info is not
>   writable.

I am trying to install **git** and need to solve this problem. Or is this a problem?

**EDIT:**
Also when I try with `sudo` like `sudo brew link automake` this time return this error:

> Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew link` You can use brew with
>   sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root. However, this
>   is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at your
>   own risk.

And nothing change.

Comment: Try `sudo brew link packagename`

Comment: see my edit on the question

Comment: Try putting this into your `.bash_profile`:  `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, then relaunch terminal and run the command (without sudo) `brew link packagename`. If that doesn't work my last suggestion would be: `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/share/info && brew doctor`

Comment: how to put bash_profile?

Comment: `echo 'export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH' >>~/.bash_profile`

Comment: your second suggest worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the directory `/usr/local/share/info` does not have the correct ownership, so try:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/share/info && brew doctor
```

It also might be necessary to include the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your profile:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```